# How to install Ubuntu onto another drive while running Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, installation, live-cd

Is there a way to install ubuntu onto a separate drive while running ubuntu? I know I can do it with via CD or USB but I don't have those at my disposal right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but AFAIK, there is not fancy wizard.  You need to build the partitions and filesystems yourself manually, then you run [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap), to do the base install.  Add the required kernel packages, and a few other non-base packages, then manually adjust your boot loader configuration.

There are [many guides](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/426) out there that cover the specific details, this procedure is commonly used for building virtual machines, livecds, chroot environments, and so on.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=debootstrap+howto
- https://www.google.com/search?q=debootstrap+howto+ubuntu

Comment: Thanks man! debootstrap is what I was looking for I think. I'm going to run with this for a few before I mark this as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: FWIW Here is the link I ended up finding helpful in doing this with ubuntu. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/debootstrap-minimal-debian-ubuntu-installation/